# New Host - Php session data being saved to specified folder, but session variables are blank/not reading the data?

Tags: php, session, variables

As the title suggests, I am having problems trying to move an existing site over to a new host.

I have edited my .htaccess find to point the php.ini session.save_path value to a new folder stored in my non public root.

This is working fine, I can see the sessions appear in this folder, with the correct entries written to them.

But for some reason, my scripts cannot make use of these sessions, as in the variables associated to them hold no value, as in, they come out blank.

Now, these scripts are in use on my old host and do work perfectly. And comparing the actual session data, once the files have been downloaded off each host, they are both exactly the same.

This leads me to think that this could be a server side issue. Possibly another php.ini value.

Has this happened to anyone before, or can anyone suggest a reason behind this kind of behavior.

It anyone has absolutely any input regrading this, or could point me in the right direction as to solve this issue. It would be more than greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

@Marc

sess.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
include 'sess2.php';
?>
```

sess2.php

```
<?php
echo ''.$test.'';
var_dump($test);
?>
```

session data file value

```
test|s:4:"test";
```

Now when I load sess.php it includes sess2.php but the page only displays the vardump which is `NULL`. This is odd because the data has been written to the session as shown in the downloaded data file value...

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `session_save_path()` at the time you do session_start()? That'd be the location PHP will be looking at that moment.

Comment: @Marc How would I find that out? I have configured my .htaccess with this line: `php_value session.save_path "N;/usr/home/bergbiz/tmp/sessions"` This is the same value that reflects when i run `phpinfo()`

Comment: phpinfo's one way, otherwise just an `echo session_save_path()` right before the session_start() would do as well.

Comment: @Marc Well that's a good point, it is supposed to add each session to its own folder, based on its uid, but I do not think that it is working with my current setup. In anycase, the same applies if the `N;` is removed.

Comment: turns out `N;` just disables auto garbage collection. learn something new every day...   have you tried a completely basic script with no framework/nothing, just a simple `session_start(); $_SESSION['test'] = 'test';`, in case it's something else nuking the sessions?

Comment: @Marc the echo produces this : `/usr/home/bergbiz/tmp/sessions` which is the same as the value held in phpinfo. I have tried a simple script to test, but will retry it now and give the results, thanks for the effort :)

Comment: @Marc Please see the edit in my op?

Comment: Looks like you're depending on `register_globals`. That's a hideously BAD thing in PHP which defaults to off these days. Try `echo $_SESSION['test']` instead now. As well, such variables are only registered at script startup time/session_start. You'd need to use session_register() (DON'T) to make it take effect during the current execution run.

Comment: @Marc You are an absolute god amoung men! I swear, i'd buy you the biggest beer!! Im not kidding, this is the umteenth time that you have solved one of my petty problems. LEGEND! Thank you so much :) Okay, I have been relying on that too much, but how would I go about doing this in the correct manner? replace all instances of `$variable` with `$_SESSION['variable']`? Was scratching my head for hours over this and, simple solution wow!

Comment: Yes, anywhere you were depending on auto-instantiated variables, you'll need to substitute in $_SESSION[...] equivalents. register globals (and all associated functionality) has been deprecated for a long time, and I really really hope it'll get ripped out of PHP outright very soon.

Comment: @Marc Okay, I was reading up on this in the php manual. It does make a bit more sense now, and its true when they say that many people just assumed that this is the way php works. I am aware of the $_session equivalent, but have not fully put its meaning together until now. Please could you post an answer so that I can choose it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're depending on register_globals. That's a hideously BAD thing in PHP which defaults to off these days. Try `echo $_SESSION['test']` instead now. As well, such variables are only registered at script startup time/session_start. You'd need to use `session_register()` (**DON'T**) to make it take effect during the current execution run